# From where can I get “Python Launcher” for Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-lion

I use a macbook (air) with OS X Lion on it. I have Python 2.7 installed already but I can't seem to find a "Python Launcher.app" anywhere on the system.

I tried installing with with pip but it couldn't find anything to fetch.

I tried searching on Google to find a downloader but my search yielded no results (for downloading).

Where can I get this app? I have a folder with 20+ subfolders of GUI examples which in turn contain anywhere from 3 to 5 subfolders. I don't want to go through each within the terminal, would much rather launch these .py scrips from the finder.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To super fantastic brilliantly potent geniuses with fantastic real-world lives and who are totally not egoistical: This question is 100% related to programming. Thank you.

Comment: Don't be upset. I think your question would have been a better fit for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/). That's probably why they closed it. But never mind, your problem could be solved in time. ;)

Comment: Thank you Peter, you are genuinely very kind, nice and helpful. SO and SE are very much luck little countries on their own with good and bad, reasonable and insane all together in some sort of harmony. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to use the OS X-internal Python distribution. Instead, install a new distribution by downloading the file

[Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer (2.7.3) for Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3-macosx10.6.dmg)

which you can find on [this webpage](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/). You will then find the Python Launcher app inside `/Applications/Python 2.7`.

Comment: Hello @PeterStahl. Thank you! I will do so. Will it break any current existing things? Dependencies, packages installed using pip etc?

Comment: @Phil No it won't break anything. You should basically leave the OSX-internal Python as it is and only use your own distribution, also for installing external libraries using `pip`. Modifying the system's Python can lead to adverse effects of the whole system in the worst case. Also, the respective environment variables will be set for you automatically, so when you enter `python` in Terminal, the interpreter of your own distribution will be started instead of the system's one. By the way, please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. Thank you. :)

Comment: Hello again @PeterStahl. Thank you for clarifying and explaining further. In future, I shall do so. Thanks again. ;-)